# I want to know how to add set of string type arraylists into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add a set of string type arraylist objects into a another arraylist to store that string type arraylist objects.

ex: `[[<, int, char], [12, &&, text], [<<, ||], [., .]]`

I have created a string type arraylist to store string values. And another ArrayList type arraylist to store string type arraylists.

I give file path as input. That file has content like this

```
while (j < 6 || j > 90) {
            i = 1;
            while (i < 6) {
                System.out.print("* ");
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            j++;
    }

    switch ( rt ) {
        case t1:

        case 12:

        case e3:

        case 43e:
    }
}
```

```
csCalculator sizeObject = new csCalculator();

                    List<Integer> csMarkList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    ArrayList<String> singleLineIdentiedTokens = new ArrayList<>();
                    Collection<ArrayList<String>> allLineIdentiedTokens = new ArrayList<>();
                    int returnCsMark = 0;

                    for(String obj:list)  {
                        singleLineIdentiedTokens = (ArrayList<String>) sizeObject.calcCsOfStatement(obj);                       
                        csMarkList.add(singleLineIdentiedTokens.size());
                        allLineIdentiedTokens.add(singleLineIdentiedTokens);

                        System.out.println(singleLineIdentiedTokens);
                        System.out.println(allLineIdentiedTokens);

                        if (!(singleLineIdentiedTokens.isEmpty())) {
                            singleLineIdentiedTokens.clear();
                        }

                     } 
                    System.out.println("CS MARK OF STATEMENT");
                    System.out.println(singleLineIdentiedTokens);
                    System.out.println(csMarkList);
```

I want expected an array like this.
[[<, int, char], [12, &&, text], [<<, ||], [., .]]

But it gives an array with last string arraylist replacing all the previous arraylist objects like this.

`[[., .], [., .], [., .], [., .]]`

I want correct that replacing defect.

Comment: Please add your complete code with example input.

Comment: I added sample input above. And the relevant code is given above. ```sizeObject.calcCsOfStatement(obj);``` 
This returns string type arraylist and it is initialized into singleLineIdentiedTokens .

Comment: Dude add complete class, it's not clear what is it "list" object in for loop. And how this Array of string is being passed. And many more things. Add complete class with test method.

Comment: Thanks bro for the support. I have got the answer. The class implementation is too big. That's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're repeatedly adding `singleLineIdentiedTokens` to `allLineIdentiedTokens`. This means that all these adds refer to the same ArrayList. Your `println(allLineIdentiedTokens)` will print something like this:

```
[singleLineIdentiedTokens.toString(), singleLineIdentiedTokens.toString(), ... ]
```

That is exactly what you're seeing, as you get:
`[[., .], [., .], [., .], [., .]]`. As you can see, the only value being kept is the last value assigned to `singleLineIdentiedTokens`. You can remedy this by altering the code as so:

```
... //logic
for(String obj:list)  {
    singleLineIdentiedTokens = (ArrayList<String>) sizeObject.calcCsOfStatement(obj);                       
    csMarkList.add(singleLineIdentiedTokens.size());
    allLineIdentiedTokens.add(new ArrayList<>(singleLineIdentiedTokens));// <- change this line

    System.out.println(singleLineIdentiedTokens);
    System.out.println(allLineIdentiedTokens);

    if (!(singleLineIdentiedTokens.isEmpty())) {
        singleLineIdentiedTokens.clear();
    }
}
... //more logic
```

What this does is keep a copy of `singleLineIdentiedTokens` at the current point in time, instead of repeatedly adding one reference that could change in value later.

Comment: P.S.: This statement: `if (!(singleLineIdentiedTokens.isEmpty())) { singleLineIdentiedTokens.clear(); }` can be reduced to `singleLineIdentiedTokens.clear();` since clear() doesn't throw on an empty list.

Comment: It worked. I changed that line. Now it gives my expected output with final the arraylist. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made the second change you mentioned in your comment above. I also worked properly.